# The file system shows there is a user, "_mysql", that I cannot "su" as root. What is basically going on so I can get mysqld running again

Tags: user-account, sudo, mysql

The following shell command sequence makes me realize I don't understand something very basic about how *user* and *group* accounts works on MacOS:

> **/tmp$** whoami
> *jondoe*
> **/tmp$** cd /usr/local/mysql/data
> **/usr/local/mysql/data$** ls -l | grep mydatabase
> drwxrwxrwx 55 **_mysql**  _mysql 1760 Jun 24 2019 *mydatabase*
> **/usr/local/mysql/data$** su
> *Password:*
> **/usr/local/mysql/data#** su xxxx
> *su: unknown login: xxxx*
> **/usr/local/mysql/data#** su _mysql
> **/usr/local/mysql/data#** whoami
> *root*
> **/usr/local/mysql/data#**

**summary**: The file system shows that the mysql installation created a user account and group account both called: "**_mysql**". Yet, when I am root, and "su" that account, I remain the root user.

**why do I care?** I ran my database fine using El Capitan. Then, I upgraded to Catalina, and now I'm having trouble (I think permission) with running *mysqld*. And, as a general "best practice", I think you are suppose to minimize the number of things running as root on your machine, yet **_mysql** and root sort of look like the same account. Of course, I really just want my db running again and understanding the **_mysql** could lead to this.

Comment: If you can, I recommend moving your MySQL (or any dev stack) from macOS and put it on a VM (VBox, Parallels, etc.) or even a Docker container. Apple is notorious for breaking things that really didn't need breaking in the first place.  Using a VM or Docker container allows *you* to control the environment and not have to deal with Apple's seemingly random whims for breaking stuff.

Answer (score 1):

My mysql database (5.6.23) became unable to start when I upgraded from El Capitan to Catalina (10.15.5). Now it works. This is what I did, but its possible some of this might not be needed or a recommended thing to do:

> **/tmp$** su
> *Password:*
> **/tmp#** cd /usr/local/mysql/data
> **/usr/local/mysql/data#** chown _mysql:_mysql *
> **/usr/local/mysql/data#** chmod 777 *
> **/usr/local/mysql/data#** exit
> **/usr/local/mysql/data$** cd /tmp
> **/tmp$** sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start &

One major error was that "*/usr/local/mysql/data/JonDoe-MacBook-Pro.local.pid could not be created*". And that was resolved by the *chown* and *chmod* commands I think. Before the *chown*, the user was **root** and group was **wheel** for files, but not directories, in */usr/local/mysql/data*.

(#1) this does not start the server

> **/tmp$** su
> *Password:*
> **/tmp#** cd /usr/local/mysql/support-files
> **/usr/local/mysql/support-files#** ./mysql.server start &

(#2) this does the server

> **/tmp$** sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start &

My understanding is that option #1 and #2 should start the server in the exact same way. This added to my not understanding.